# Отправить POST запрос не ожидая ответ, но получив поток ответа C#

Tags: c#, httpclient

Мне надо отправить POST запрос, при этом сразу же получить поток данного ответа, желательно через `HttpRequestMessage`, но не обязательно.

Как я понял сейчас он ожидает ответ от сервера

А мне бы хотелось сразу же получить `Stream` объект ответа

Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=net-7.0

Comment: @CrazyElf это GET, а надо POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте опцию `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new();
```

```
public async Task<Stream> PostAsync(string url)
{
    using HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    request.Content = ...; // контент для отправки
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

```
Stream responseStream = await PostAsync(url);
```